# How to change the order of list of in-app purchases in appstore app information section?

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store, itunes

I have more than 20 in-app purchase subscription plans inside my app. I want to show few selected plans inside the Appstore information section and also I need to reorder that based on my subscription plans. Right now it's showing randomly from the in-app purchase list.

Is there any way I can customize this and show the plans based on my requirement?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way is to sort it alphabetically or by price amount.

here is an example with react native while its not swift you cane create similar results
products.sort((item,item2)=> item.price > item2.price ) // will sort the
products ascending based on price.

where products is a jason that contains an array of JavaScript objects

Object {
"description": "best service for one great price",
"price": "$24.82",
"priceAmountMicros": 24820000,
"priceCurrencyCode": "USD",
"productId": "one_session",
"subscriptionPeriod": "P0D",
"title": "one session",
"type": 0,
}

Comment: This code cannot be used to control the sorting of in-app purchases inside the App Store.